# How to seralize dataview object in json

Tags: vb.net

Hello all i have code snippet like this

```
  Case "adhoc_searchResult"
                    Dim cubeid As Integer = Request("cubeid")
                    Dim dimArr As String = Request("dimArr")
                    Dim tmethod As String = Request("tmethod")
                    Dim tstr As String = Request("tstr")
                    Dim search_result As DataView = New DataView()

                    search_result = HostAnalytics.HostAnalyzer.HostAnalyzer.getDimensionSearchResults(cubeid, dimArr, tmethod, tstr)
                    Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(search_result))

                Case Else
                    Response.Write("Invalid call")
            End Select
        Catch ex As Exception
            Common.GetLogErrorInJson("105", "Following error occurred while getting data : " & ex.Message & " :: " & ex.StackTrace().ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Here in  the vb method, it is returning Dataview object, and now i am serializing this with `jsonconver.serializeObject()`.
but it is throwing an expcetion stating like that cirular reference occurs...
but the `getDimensionSearchResult()` method returning correct value, that value is not capturing in this code block.
 how to overcome this and is there any mistake in my code, please help me.

Thanks